# Как blob.sql конвертировать на String

Tags: java, jdbc, extjs

Есть вывод с базы JDBC, и там прописан код

```
                   str += ("[" +
                    "'" + rs.getInt("ID") + "', " +
                    "'" + rs.getString("NAME") + "',  " +
                    "'" + rs.getString("TYPE") + "',  " +
                    "'" + rs.getString("DATA") + "', " +
                    "'" + rs.getBlob("MESSAGE") + "', " +
                    "'" + rs.getInt("ID2") + "', " +
                    "'" + rs.getString("NAMEDOCUMENT") + "', " +
                    "'" + rs.getInt("ID1") + "', " +
                    "'" + rs.getString("STATUS") +
                    "'],");
```

поля `Message` у меня типа `blob`, и когда я принимаю его в Ext JS то `value` у него ссылка на объект как конвертировать что бы на Ext JS выходило значения ??

Comment: Вы как нибудь пробовали вывести значение?

Comment: да, rs.getString("Message") но компилятор ругается и говорит что метод getString для блоба не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BLOB` (binary large object) — это двоичные данные неспецифицированного формата. Не очень понятно, почему у вас `Message` (вероятно, текстовые данные) хранятся в виде `BLOB`. Для больших текстовых данных должен использоваться тип `CLOB` (character large object).

Если вы хотите вывести содержимое `BLOB`, интерпретируя его, как текст, вам надо знать, в какой кодировке этот текст был туда записан. Предположим, `UTF-8`. Тогда можно сделать так:

```
// ограничим максимальную длину блока данных, чтобы память не кончилась
int LENGTH_LIMIT = 100_000; 
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("MESSAGE");
long length = blob.length();
// а лучше кидать исключение, если неожиданно слишком большая длина
if(length > LENGTH_LIMIT) length = LENGTH_LIMIT;
byte[] data = blob.getBytes(0, (int)length);
String message = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// теперь используйте message
```

В заключение скажу, что формировать JSON конкатенацией строк очень плохо. Вы сильно попадёте на первой одинарной кавычке внутри текста сообщения. Есть много готовых библиотек для того, чтобы сделать это быстро и безопасно.

Comment: да но мне нужен именно blob, есть такое по короче Blob blob = rs.getBlob("MESSAGE");
                    byte[] bdata = rs.getBlob("MESSAGE").getBytes(1, (int) rs.getBlob("MESSAGE").length());
                    String text = new String(bdata);  но мне нужно именно на jdbc

Comment: Ваше «покороче» молча переполнит длину, если она большая, и использует системную кодировку по умолчанию, которая может не иметь ничего общего с реальной кодировкой в базе и может поменяться, например, на другом хостинге.